# Is it possible to somehow track the state when a scroll is needed in a UITextView? Swift

Tags: swift, textview

I working in collectionViewCell. I upload API data, and I want to check if the number of lines in the UITextView is more than 4, then I need a isScrollEnabled = true, if not, then = false. How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to get number of lines

```
extension UITextView {

    func numberOfLines() -> Int {
        let layoutManager = self.layoutManager
        let numberOfGlyphs = layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs
        var lineRange: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
        var index = 0
        var numberOfLines = 0

        while index < numberOfGlyphs {
            layoutManager.lineFragmentRect(forGlyphAt: index, effectiveRange: &lineRange)
            index = NSMaxRange(lineRange)
            numberOfLines += 1
        }
        return numberOfLines
    }

}
```

To call it

```
let count = textView.numberOfLines()
print(count)
```